# How to count consecutive row where one column have a specific value in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data set that looks like this

```
gId mId
226 88825
226 88825
226 88825
226 88825
226 88825
226 88825
226 88832
226 88832
226 88832
226 88832
226 88863
226 88863
226 88863
226 88863
226 88863
227 89080
227 89080
227 89080
227 89148
227 89148
227 89148
227 89197
227 89197
227 89197
227 89148
227 89197
227 89197
227 89197
227 89197
227 89148
227 89197
227 89197
227 89197
227 89197
227 89148
227 89197
227 89197
227 89197
229 89267
229 89318
229 89322
231 90257
231 90340
231 90350
247 94318
247 94318
249 94642
249 94642
249 94642
249 94400
249 94642    
249 94642
249 94642
249 94642
249 94642
249 94642
249 94400
249 94400
249 94400
249 94400
```

I need to be able to get a list of the unique `gId` column where the `mId` column contains the same value in 5 or more consecutive rows. So the above data set will return something like this

```
gId mId
226 88825
226 88863
249 94642
```

One important thing to mention that I can't change the order of this list so I have to count it top to bottom to be able to check for consecutive rows.

My table looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE t (
   gId int NOT NULL, 
   mId int NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* tables.  There is no concept of conductive rows, unless another column specifies the ordering.

Comment: Should we assume that by '_conservative_ rows' you mean '_consecutive_ rows'?

Comment: consecutive is what I meant to type. I apologize for this typo. I just updated my question

Comment: What other columns are in the table?  Which one is the primary key?  Would you update your sample data to include the primary key and its data?

Comment: It is not possible to "count it top to bottom" as you put it.   Tables do not have a top or bottom.   You can only get what you want if there is a column(s) that you can ORDER BY.

Comment: You do not have enough information in the table to answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a version of SQL Server that supports common table expressions, this should do the trick:

```
WITH AtLeastFive AS (
    SELECT  gId, mId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY gId, mId ORDER BY gId, mId) AS RowNum
    FROM    t
)
SELECT * FROM AtLeastFive WHERE RowNum =5
```

Comment: Of course, if the consecutive factor is dependent on something else, like the physical order of rows, you will have to substitute some determining column in the ROW_NUMBER function... like a CreateDate column.

Comment: Thank you. That seems to be giving the correct dataset

Comment: You're welcome. Its important to understand that the ordering of data cannot be guaranteed without an appropriate ORDER BY (as @Tab Alleman stated in his comment to your question). Provided that the gId's can be out of order physically, but straightened out logically with an ORDER BY, you'll be in fine shape :)

Comment: @MikeA: If this select returns the correct dataset your question is wrong :-)  It will return `227 89197`and there are no five consecutive rows for this combination (without another column which determines the order there's no way to get a result matching your problem description). In fact this query is a complicated way to get the same result as `SELECT gId, mId FROM tab GROUP BY gld, mld HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5`.